# Python Open AI - simple chat boot gpt 3.5

Tags: python, openai-api

i have problem in speak function
i write simple probragm load api on open AI its ok
clearing function is ok
but speak function throw exception ? i dont now why ?
pleas help i paste code here

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
import os
import openai
import pickle
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("Chat Bot GPT 3.5")
app.geometry("750x600")
app.iconbitmap("ai_lt.ico")
def speak():
    print("Speak")
    file_name = "api_key"
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            input_file = open(file_name, "rb")
            api_key_value = pickle.load(input_file)

            openai.api_key = api_key_value
            openai.Model.list()


            response = openai.Completion.create(
                model = "text-davinci-003",
                prompt = chat_entry.get(),
                temperature = 0,
                max_tokens = 4000,
                top_p = 1,
                frequency_penalty = 0.0,
                presence_penalty = 0.0
            )
            # editedResponse = response["choices"][0]["text"].strip()
            # my_text.insert(END, "\n")
            my_text.insert(END, response)
        else:
            my_text.insert(END, "\n\n Brak klucz lub blędny klucz \n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception  speak!!")
def clear():
    print("czyść")
    my_text.delete(1.0, END)
    chat_entry.delete(0, END)
def api():
    print("API")
    file_name = "api_key"
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            input_file = open(file_name, "rb")
            api_key_value = pickle.load(input_file)
            api_entry.insert(END, api_key_value)
            input_file.close()
        else:
            input_file = open(file_name, "wb")
            input_file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception !!")

    api_frame.pack(pady=10)
    app.geometry("750x750")
```

I looked at the code ad prin function to see where program stoping
and add exception function

Comment: What exception it throws? Saying it throws an exception is not helpful at all. I suggest removing the try except Exception block.